# Background image doesn't show when defined in stylesheet with sublime text

Tags: html, css, background, sublimetext2, background-image

I don't know why but my browser (firefox) don't show me my background-image, when i put it on html it works.

my editor : sublime text 2
i use MAMP too.

my css code :

```
.home{
background-image: url('bg-img.jpg');
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Can you help me ? Thanks

Rémi

Comment: is `bg-img.jpg` in the same directory as your style sheet because thats where its looking for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the other answers/comments are on the right track.  My guess is the image is not in the right relative path to the style sheet.  If your CSS file is in a folder off your web root such as `http://example.com/css/site.css`, then the browser is going to look for the background image at `http://example.com/css/bg-img.jpg` ... which would be a pretty odd place to put it.

Try putting the full path to the file in your css...something like this:

```
.home{
background-image: url('/images/bg-img.jpg');
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

(And make sure that bg-img.jpg actually lives in /images/, of course!)

I give even odds of that fixing the problem.

If it doesn't, open the page in the browser, right click and choose "Inspect Element" or similar.  Then you can dig around and see if your css looks like you expect it to, see if you're getting any 404's returned, etc.  This should lead you very quickly to the problem.

Failing all that, try it in a different browser.

BTW, I don't think this could have anything to do with Sublime.

ps.  If you're still battling this, please edit your question to include the full css file and html and a link to the live page.

Answer (score 1):

1-perhaps your div.home is empty so not enough  height to display it .(for example use height : 200px to see it)

2-another reason is about your img url . if its in a folder like images you should try this

```
.home{
background-image: url('images/bg-img.jpg');
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) , but it still not working . I've try your 2 answer but i think it's sublime who doesn't work correctly when i put an image in the html with url (img/name.jpeg) my browser show the image but not in the stylesheet. it's strange.

Answer (score 1):

if you want add background-image in sublime...

```
body {
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-image: url(../images/background.gif);
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use screenshot but copy/paste your code...$